# All binary sequences with length n

Tags: list-manipulation, binary

I don't know if there is a built-in function for this, but I'm thinking about something like this

```
Outer[List, Table[{0,1},{n}] ]
```

But `Outer` doesn't accept this type of input. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html) is surely better but you can make `Outer` work very simply too:

```
Outer[List, ##] & @@ Table[{0, 1}, {3}]
```

> ```
> {{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}},
>  {{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}}
> ```

Also applicable is [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[List, {2, 2, 2}, 0]
```

> ```
> {{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}},
>  {{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}}
> ```

Complete with flattening:

```
n = 4;
{Array[List, ConstantArray[2, n], 0, ## &]}
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1},
>  {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1},
>  {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1},
>  {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

Answer (score 12):

You could try `Tuples`:

```
Tuples[{0, 1}, 4]

(*
  {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},
   {0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1},
   {1,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,1},
   {1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,1},{1,1,1,0},{1,1,1,1}}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

While `Tuples` works well for generating all of them at once, sometimes we need to enumerate them one by one, without keeping all previous results in memory.  In this case you can use

```
Do[ ... IntegerDigits[k, 2, n] ...,  {k, 0, 2^n-1}]
```

Comment: What does the `...` do? I get a syntax error when I execute it.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Nothing.  It's not executable code, I meant that one might want to put other things in the `Do` loop.

Comment: @Dumps I use `. . .` for that purpose to reduce confusion with `RepeatedNull`; I'm not sure if it works.

Answer (score 4):

```
IntegerDigits[Range[2^5], 2, 5]
```

or as a function:

```
myList[n_: Integer] := Flatten[Array[List, Table[2, {n}], 0], n - 1]
```

But if you need to display the digits as a string rather than a comma-separated list:

```
StringJoin /@ Tuples[{"0", "1"}, 5]
```

What is your specific need for such sequences?  That will help us help you.

Comment: As to the second solution: don't forget `IntegerString`: `With[{n = 8}, IntegerString[#, 2, n] & /@ Range[2^n - 1]]`. It's twice as fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
Distribute[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 4], List] // TeXForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$